# Submit button is submitting the first form in the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, form-submit, submit-button

I am trying to make an MVC 5 Razor web page with a table within it, Every row in this table contains a Delete button which is post action:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            .
            .
            .
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                .
                .
                .
                <td>
                    @using(Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Person", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        @html.AntiForgetyToken()
                        @html.Hidden("personId", item.PersonId)

                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Delete</button>
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And in the controller:

```
public class PersonController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(int personId)
    {
        // Do Something...
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when pressing Delete button in any row of the table it always submitting the first form in the page which means the first person in the table is always being deleted no matter what submit button i press.
Any ideas to solve this issue?

**Edit:**
The generated page html

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h2>Person List</h2>
</div>

<table class="row table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="text-primary">
            <th class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">5</td>
            <td>Ismail</td>
            <td>ismail@example.com</td>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>
                <form action="/WebApp/Person/Delete?PersonID=5" method="post">
                    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="Uxhp0Bq1ATAwOXNODHmc74f12O2-dvFhQ5kletbmDkq64CEPWZlXXPKuHDoqSy4DXF6mJhYfGffc_YAn1yERxp69JCUT9IlGTKdfirvVvqE1" />
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="/WebApp/Person/Details?PersonID=5">View</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="/WebApp/Person/Edit?PersonID=5">Edit</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">6</td>
            <td>MoHaKa</td>
            <td>MoHaKa@example.com</td>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>
                <form action="/WebApp/Person/Delete?PersonID=6" method="post">
                    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="R4CUAuVpbGihZvrFxxCjCL_oJ7tgkS_Xxh67i_xCpMXpvZKR5ASUWrSCvjg52yRorF-Ypeau1oZwDi96caHyUj-gmBeHnx7NBgfJBLkLPnQ1" />
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="/WebApp/Person/Details?PersonID=6">View</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="/WebApp/Person/Edit?PersonID=6">Edit</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger>Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>                    
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: My eyes could be deceiving me, but I don't see the `hidden` input for the `personId` that should be part of the POST payload in the generated page.

Comment: Yes but @AlexPolyankin asked me to remove the hidden input and use routeValues instead, it giving the same result by the way

Comment: Your `controller` is restricted to `HttpPost` (not `GET`) - debug your controller and check what value you get for the `personId` param).

Comment: I always get the Id value of the first person in the table

Comment: Huh? *Without* passing the `int` param in your `POST`? You're not getting a `null` exception given the code you have above?

Comment: @MoHaKa Your html is 100% correct. If there is a problem, it is out of the scope of this code. Try intercepting form posting with browser developer tools (`F12`), or with Fiddler and post results.

Comment: you are passing PersonID from view but getting  personId in the controller as a parameter. It should be same. Please change it and then try. Otherwise your code seems ok.

Comment: It is not working @Shariful_Islam, by the way personId is not case-sensitive in this situation

Comment: I don't know @AlexPolyankin, I am about throwing my PC from the window

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your form code:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Person", new { item.PersonId }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgetyToken()
    <button class="btn">Delete</button>
}
```

ASP.NET MVC default action behavior: primitive types are first looked in query string.

Comment: Are you sure that it will generate right route? Shouldn't it be `new { personId = item.PersonId }`?

Comment: @teovankot Yes, this is shortcut. More info [here](http://csharp.2000things.com/tag/anonymous-types/).

Comment: I did tried that, it is not working neither, the Id of the first person in the table is coming in personId parameter

Comment: @MoHaKa Can you post generated page html?

Comment: @AlexPolyankin `PersonId` not same as `personId` so possibly @teo right

Comment: @Grundy it is case-insensitive .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to use just one form and add a cell like this instead of several forms:

```
<td onclick="window.location='@Url.Action("Delete", new { PersonID = item.PersonId })'" style="cursor:pointer;">
</td>
```